# Visual basic Making a global round function

Tags: vb.net, rounding

I am working in on a project which is some sort of a calculator for Quadratic equations and others parts. One of the tasks is to make an accuracy option to make the user set the rounding between 1-5 decimal places.

I have constructed some sort of function already to do that, however what I need is a way for the program to round the values when there are two different results(i.e quadratic equations), if I use my function to kinda joins the two answers and rounds them.

How do i make the variable that holds the results, and the function that rounds the result be able to store two different answers without joining them? or maybe I have written the code not how it is supposed to be? any tips?

I am using the Math.round function.

Here is the code;

```
Function Accuracy()
    Dim choice As Integer = 0
    Console.WriteLine("This is the accuracy option")
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the decimals places to be set from 1 - 5")
    DP = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.WriteLine("The current decimals places are set to: " & DP)
    ...

Function round()
    Result = Math.Round(Result, DP)
End Function
```

The way i tried to make it work was by making the result = to "result" of the calculation and then run the round() function

- DP and result are global variables.

Comment: Are you using VB .net or VBA ? tags unclear... I would create a class that can store both value, a real result and a rounded one...

Comment: based on `Console` and `Math` classes I'd say this isn't VBA

Comment: Never intentionally throw calculation accuracy away.  Only round for the benefit of human eyes, do so with composite formatting.

Comment: I am using visual studio, visual basic console application. srry for the tags im new to forums and im new to this language. im more used to c++.

Comment: One quick question also, how do I include a class or a module into another one?

Answer (score -1):

Ok here is basically the structure I would build. Keep in mind I don't know about your project and even less about quadratic equations...

**File MyResult.vb**

```
Public Class MyResult
   Public Property Result as Double 'I suppose
   Public Property RoundedDecimals as Integer 'We hold here the rouding
   Public Readonly Property RoundedResult as Double
   Get
     Return Math.Round(Result, RoundedDecimals)
   End Get
   End Property

   Public Sub New(Result as Double)
     Me.Result = Result
     RoundedDecimals = 5
   End Sub

   '... End of your class
End Class
```

**File MainModule.vb**

```
Public Module MainModule

  Sub Main()
    'Calculate your stuff
    ...        

    'Create your result 
    Dim Result As New MyResult(CalculatedValue)

    'Ask for Rounding
    Dim round = 0
    Do
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number of decimals : ")
        round = Console.ReadLine()
    while not Integer.TryParse(round, Result.RoundedDecimals)

    'Displaying rounded result
    Console.WriteLine("Rounded Result is {0}", Result.RoundedResult)

    '...
  End Sub()

End Module
```

Comment: and in order to make the user enter the rounding value just do RoundedDecimals = console.readline() ??

Comment: and wil the class be found in module1 or do create new class?? if so how do i link the class with the module, i know how to do it in c++ but idk how in VB

Comment: how do i make the result of the calculation then use the class to round?

Comment: @Bart123 I can't answer right now, but tomorrow I will be able to complete the answer if nobody else did...

Comment: so there is no need to do something like "#include MyResult.vb" ? they are just included if u make the variables public? , coz im c++ u have to include classes or others.

Comment: the program basically hold the result and round it right, so do i need to make new variables to hold results for other calculations and round them again? or how do i make the result that i have created to be somehow universal ? i u know hat i mean. Coz basically i have lots of results to be rounded and displayed at the same time.